# Dynamically Generating sitemap.xml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms, sitemap

I've implemented a sitemap that is dynamically generated on the fly using the technique described [here](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/asp/dynamic-sitemaps-in-asp-net).

Since my site is a WebForms app, my sitemap URL ends up being www.mydomain.com/Sitemap.aspx.

This is working well, and I can use search engine webmaster tools to tell them the URL to my sitemap. However, smaller search engines may not know where to find this file. It would be better if my dynamically generated sitemap could be at www.mydomain.com/sitemap.xml. This is the standard URL for a sitemap.

What is the easiest way to generate the same sitemap data I do now but have it appear as the file sitemap.xml. Can I do it using routing, or do I need a custom HTTP handler?

I'm using webforms but also have sites using ASP.NET MVC so I'm very interested in finding the best technique to do this in both platforms.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For Webforms, you can use HttpModule, check out [UrlRewriting.NET](http://urlrewriting.net/149/en/home.html)

For MVC, use routing:

```
routes.MapRoute("Sitemap", 
                "sitemap.xml",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Sitemap" })
```

Comment: Hmm... The MVC solution seems ideal here. The Webforms solution, not so much (a third-party control that requires IIS to be running and may or may not work in future versions of ASP.NET). I do plan to rewrite the site to MVC but not any time soon. Thanks.

Comment: If the OP is using IIS 7 or higher there is a native [Url rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) for the web server. It is much more convenient. No coding. Just a few lines in web.config.

Comment: @Oybek Yes, we're using the latest software all around. Looks like this will be of interest to me. (Although I'm using shared hosting and may not have access to all IIS settings.) Thanks.

Comment: Second that, use Url Rewrite if you have IIS7+

Answer (score 2):

For Webforms, you can also update your web.config as mentioned above, you just use plain aspx or ascx page and then do magic with rewrite :-) (I use .net 4.0)

e.g.

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Main Sitemap" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^sitemap.xml"/>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="sitemap/sitemap.aspx" appendQueryString="false"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: This looked promising but I haven't been able to get it to work. This particular site is still built with Visual Studio 2010. I don't know if that has something to do with it.

Comment: Anyway, I played with this and `routes.MapPageRoute("Sitemap", "Sitemap.xml", "~/Sitemap.aspx");` seems to work fine. Still testing...

Comment: I installed URL Rewrite and used this XML and ignored the Visual Studio warning and it worked great.